# Mongodb download option for community server not available

Tags: mongodb, download, community-server

So I need to download Mongodb community server for my class. However, the download option itself is not present in the mongodb page! I am using windows and internet explorer to do this.

The options of version, platform, package and the download button is not present, but merely a link which doesn't work itself. I am confused on how to proceed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try the current version of a chromium-based browser.

Comment: Were you going to `https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community`?

Answer (score 0):

You can download any past or current version of MongoDB from the [Archive Page](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community/releases/archive). Make sure to select the correct architecture (Windows) for the version you're interested in downloading.